# Websphere applications loaded jars - classpath conflict - MQ server upgrade

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq

We have recently upgraded our MQ server for the application that is in WebSphere. We are currently using `com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.1.0.2.jar` which is compatible for the MQ server's version. However, `RC=2059;AMQ9503` error. The same jar is working fine in Jboss server, but giving above error in Websphere 8X version. I suspect Websphere runtime, which has the similar jar, causing this issue. Our application classloader property is "Parent loader first", so I tried even to define this jar as a start up jar in classpath, and even that didn't work. Is there a way to check all the jars loaded into the application in Websphere? or anyway I can resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of WAS are you running,  please provide all four digits.  Can you also find out what error is logged in the queue managers `AMQERR01.LOG` at the time you get 2059.  I'm also positive any WAS v8 would be incompatible with a MQ version greater than 7.5.  Also in most cases you would use the Resource Adapter (rar) not a jar.

Comment: @Shakti Kumar As JoshMc says, Websphere Application Server v8.x includes an IBM MQ Resource Adapter (RA) to support deployed JMS applications. [This doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031610_.htm) explains the role of the RA and its config. You shouldn't need to bundle the MQ client jars with your application.

Comment: WAAS 8.5 is the version

Answer (score 0):

**Answer-attempt based on previous try-and-error attempts:**

> Is there a way to check all the jars loaded into the application in
> Websphere?

You can view the Classes loaded by clicking on

Applications > Enterprise Applications > (deployed app) > Manage Modules > (your web app module) > Class loader viewer

This should present you with a page were you can expand the modules to see their loaded classes. If you do not have this view, you probably have to activate the class loader viewer service by setting the checkbox on

Servers > application servers > (your application server, probably server1) > class loader viewer service.

Alternatively, you can also write the classes into native_stdout.log, by activating the logging of class loaders used by checking

Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine, option "verbose class loading"

and restarting the server.

> or anyway I can resolve this issue?

You can try to set the class loading order to "parent last" to force websphere to load your jar first (if not already done). There are multiple places that have this setting, see

Applications > +Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > (deployed app) > Class loading and update detection

and

Enterprise Applications > (deployed app) > Manage Modules > (your web module), see Dropdown "class loader order"

and also

Application servers > (your application server, probably server1) > class loader policy "Single" and then the dropdown "class loading mode"

(I hope one of those options or experiences is helpful, other options may include setting the jar in question as shared library)